# Html Input File not working if page contains master page

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page with Form tag

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

And in the page i have HtmlInputFile

```
   <input id="File1" 
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          runat="server"/>       
<input type="button" 
          id="Button1" 
          value="Upload" 
          OnServerClick="Button1_Click" 
          runat="server"/>
```

and the handler

```
       void Button1_Click(object Source, EventArgs e) 
   {

      if (File1.PostedFile != null) 
      {
         try 
         {
           HttpPostedFile file = File1.PostedFile;
             byte[] fileContent = new byte[file.ContentLength];

             file.InputStream.Read(fileContent, 0, file.ContentLength);
         }
         catch (Exception exc) 
         {

         }
      }
   }
```

But always PostedFile = null !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the ASP.NET control:

```
<asp:FileUpload id="File1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: additionally, with the ASP.NET control, you don't need to specify the enctype or method in your form tag.  That is all generated by the framework as needed.

Comment: AND you can use the button control as well which facilitates things even further.

Comment: AND you can use File1.HasFile to insure a file is selected - I prefer that to the null comparison (could just be me).

Comment: I have tried FileUpload & AsyncFileUpload but it is not working also and don't fire the uploading action.So I have tended to use HtmlInputFile

Comment: Well it's pretty simple stuff. Please refer to any website Google gives you, like http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/. Try to copy that code into your project and check if it works. If i doesn't, there's something wrong elsewhere. It has nothing to do with MasterPage issues.